# Python grouped iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, pagination

I wanted to write an iterator that would split items up into groups, so I can bulk insert into MySQL without crashing or overwhelming the server.

This is the implementation I came up with.
I am hoping that when yielding from the list it's not creating a copy / clone of the list.

I need more experience with Python internals to be able to debug and profile this function I wrote.

```
def iter_group(iterable, batch_size:int):
    iterable_type = type(iterable)
    length = len(iterable)
    start = batch_size*-1
    end = 0
    while(end < length):
        start += batch_size
        end += batch_size
        if iterable_type == list:
            yield (iterable[i] for i in range(start,min(length-1,end)))
        else:
            yield iterable[start:end]

#test data

items = range(0,10001)
for item_group in iter_group(items, 1000):
    for item in item_group:
        print(item,end=' ')
```

Answer (score 7):

We can improve readability of your code as follows:

- using type annotations partially looks incomplete, when we can be more descriptive:

  ```
  from typing import (Iterable, 
                      TypeVar)

  ElementType = TypeVar('ElementType')


  def iter_group(iterable: Iterable[ElementType],
                 batch_size: int) -> Iterable[Iterable[ElementType]]:
      ...
  ```
- checking if object has given type should be done using [`isinstance` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), so instead of

  ```
  iterable_type = type(iterable)
  ...
  if iterable_type == list:
      ...
  ```

  we can simply write

  ```
  if isinstance(iterable, list):
      ...
  ```

  (btw I don't understand why are you treating `list` as a special case)
- if you want negate a number then we can use `-` unary operator, no need to multiply by `-1`, so instead of

  ```
  start = batch_size * -1
  ```

  we can write

  ```
  start = -batch_size
  ```
- no need in parentheses for `while`-loop condition, we are not in `C`/`C++`/`JAVA`, we can simply write:

  ```
  while end < length:
      ...
  ```
- setting `start` to `-batch_size` and `end` to `0` and change them right after that seems redundant when we can set them to `0` and `batch_size` respectfully and increment at the end of the `while` loop body, so instead

  ```
  start = batch_size * -1
  end = 0
  while end < length:
      start += batch_size
      end += batch_size
      ...
  ```

  we can write

  ```
  start = 0
  end = batch_size
  while end < length:
      ...
      start += batch_size
      end += batch_size
  ```

---

If I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve is to split iterable into evenly sized chunks, which is [a well-known StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks), but accepted answer works only for sequences (`str`/`list`/`tuple`) and so does your solution. For example it won't work for potentially infinite sequences like classic Fibonacci numbers generator

```
>>> def fibonacci():
        a, b = 0, 1
        while True:
            yield a
            a, b = b, a + b
>>> next(iter_group(fibonacci(), 5))
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
        length = len(iterable)
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

If you want to work with arbitrary iterables (e.g. `generator`s), we may use `itertools` module and [this brilliant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22045226/5997596) which uses [`iter` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) form with sentinel value

```
from itertools import islice
from typing import (Iterable,
                    Tuple,
                    TypeVar)

ElementType = TypeVar('ElementType')


def chunks(iterable: Iterable[ElementType],
           batch_size: int) -> Iterable[Tuple[ElementType, ...]]:
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    return iter(lambda: tuple(islice(iterator, batch_size)), ())
```

but if we make a simple benchmark with

```
def sequence_chunks(iterable: Sequence[ElementType],
                    batch_size: int) -> Iterable[Sequence[ElementType]]:
    for start in range(0, len(iterable), batch_size):
        yield iterable[start:start + batch_size]
```

like

```
import timeit

...
print('original solution',
      min(timeit.repeat('list(iter_group(iterable, 1000))',
                        'from __main__ import iter_group\n'
                        'iterable = range(0, 10001)',
                        number=10000)))
print('Ned Batchelder\'s solution',
      min(timeit.repeat('list(sequence_chunks(iterable, 1000))',
                        'from __main__ import sequence_chunks\n'
                        'iterable = range(0, 10001)',
                        number=10000)))
print('senderle\'s solution',
      min(timeit.repeat('list(chunks(iterable, 1000))',
                        'from __main__ import chunks\n'
                        'iterable = range(0, 10001)',
                        number=10000)))
```

on my laptop with Windows 10 and Python 3.5 we'll have

```
original solution 0.07320549999999999
Ned Batchelder's solution 0.06249870000000002
senderle's solution 2.6072023999999994
```

so how can we have both speed and handle cases with non-sequence iterables?

Here comes `functools` module with [`singledispatch` function decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch). We can use it like

```
import timeit
from collections import abc
from functools import singledispatch
from itertools import islice
from typing import (Iterable,
                    Sequence,
                    TypeVar)

ElementType = TypeVar('ElementType')


@singledispatch
def chunks(iterable: Iterable[ElementType],
           batch_size: int) -> Iterable[Iterable[ElementType]]:
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    return iter(lambda: tuple(islice(iterator, batch_size)), ())


@chunks.register(abc.Sequence)
def sequence_chunks(iterable: Sequence[ElementType],
                    batch_size: int) -> Iterable[Iterable[ElementType]]:
    for start in range(0, len(iterable), batch_size):
        yield iterable[start:start + batch_size]
```

after that call to `chunks` will end up in `sequence_chunks` for sequences and in general `chunks` for all other cases.

But

```
print('single-dispatched solution',
      min(timeit.repeat('list(chunks(iterable, 1000))',
                        'from __main__ import chunks\n'
                        'iterable = range(0, 10001)',
                        number=10000)))
```

gives

```
single-dispatched solution 0.0737681
```

so we lose some time during dispatching, but we can save some time and space if we will use `itertools.islice` for sequences as well like

```
@chunks.register(abc.Sequence)
def sequence_chunks(iterable: Sequence[ElementType],
                    batch_size: int) -> Iterable[Iterable[ElementType]]:
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for _ in range(ceil_division(len(iterable), batch_size)):
        yield islice(iterator, batch_size)


def ceil_division(left_number: int, right_number: int) -> int:
    """
    Divides given numbers with ceiling.
    """
    # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17511341/5997596
    return -(-left_number // right_number)
```

which gives

```
complete single-dispatched solution 0.03895900000000002
```

## P.S.

@AJNeufeld's solution gives

```
0.0647120000000001
```

on my laptop

Comment: Note: `list(sequence_chunks(range(0, 10001), 1000))` return `[ <itertools.islice object>, <itertools.islice object>, ..., <itertools.islice object> ]` where `list(iter_group(range(10001), 1000))` returns `[range(0, 1000), range(1000, 2000), ..., range(10000, 10001)]`.  And `list(chunks(range(0, 10001), 1000))` returns `[(0, 1, 2, ..., 998, 999), (1000, 1001, ..., 1999), ... , (10000, ) ]`!  These are very, very different animals.

Comment: Note: `itertools.islice()` has **not** advanced the iterator (singular) in the returned list of slices.  If we assign `x = list(sequence_chunks(range(0, 10001), 1000))`, and then ask for the `next()` values of the third, second and first iterators, `[ next(x[2]), next(x[1]), next(x[0])]` you might expect `[2000, 1000, 0]`, but you will actually get `[0, 1,  2]`!

Comment: @AJNeufeld: I know, but in OP there is a statement `(iterable[i] for i in range(start,min(length-1,end)))`, so I thought `iterator`s are satisfactory choice, especially if author wants to insert records in batches

Comment: ```
start = 0
end = batch_size
while end < length:
    ...
    start += batch_size
    end += batch_size
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code cannot work with iterables of unknown length:

```
def unknown_length():
    i = 0
    while i < 12:
        yield i
        i += 1

items = iter(unknown_length())
for item_group in iter_group(items, 5):
    for item in item_group:
        print(item,end=' ')
    print()
```

> TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

---

<strike>This code `(iterable[i] for i in range(start,min(length-1,end)))` is creating a new tuple containing a shallow copy of each group of `batch_size` items, although only 1 at a time so you aren't ending up with a complete copy of the iterable all at once, requiring double the memory.</strike>

---

The `range(start,min(length-1,end))` omits the your last data item!  The end limit is non-inclusive, so the last item you get is `iterable[length-2]`.

---

The following `iter_group` yields a nested generator which `yield` items until `batch_size` items have been returned.  Then, the next nested generator will be yielded, until the list item has been produced.

```
def iter_group(iterable, batch_size:int):
    it = iter(iterable)

    def group(first):
        yield first
        try:
            for _ in range(batch_size - 1):
                yield next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            pass

    try:
        while True:
            yield group(next(it))
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

If you want to try to optimize this for sliceable iterables, you could try:

```
def iter_group(iterable, batch_size:int):

    try:
        # Maybe we can use slices?
        start = 0
        n = len(iterable)
        while start < n:
            yield iterable[start:start+batch_size]
            start += batch_size

    except TypeError:
        # Nope!  Couldn't get either the length or a slice.

        it = iter(iterable)

        def group(first):
            yield first

            try:
                for _ in range(batch_size - 1):
                    yield next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                pass

        try:
            while True:
                yield group(next(it))
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

Comment: statement `(iterable[i] for i in range(start,min(length-1,end)))` does not create a new `tuple`, but a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov You're right - good catch.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov does it return a NEW generator expression, or does it set the state of the existing expression?

Comment: @Ben It will yield a new generator expression each time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will work with any iterable, not just sequences.  It does not create any intermediate objects aside from the group iterator, and so should be efficient.

```
def grouped(items, size):
    iterator = iter(items)
    more = True
    while more:
        def group():
            nonlocal more
            count = 0
            while count == 0 or count % size != 0:
                try:
                    yield next(iterator)
                except StopIteration:
                    more = False
                    return
                count += 1
        yield group()

        
for count, group in enumerate(grouped(range(33), 10)):
    print(count)
    print('   ', list(group))
```

Output:

```
0
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1
    [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
2
    [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
3
    [30, 31, 32]
```

`islice` has a decent amount of overhead, and so calling it for each group is going to slow things down a bit if you call it in tight loops.  However in practice for the OP's use case, I really doubt that will be significant, and so I think solutions using it are just fine.  In fact for doing database operations, the performance of your grouping function is unlikely to be a factor at all unless you're doing something horribly wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  It's usually best to begin your answer with the actual review.  Code that implements your suggested improvements is always welcome, but prefer to put that at the end, as it's really just a supplement to the review itself, and not everyone will want to read that far.  Please do stay around and continue answering questions here; I think you have a lot to offer!